# Override measure/arrange will hide button control

Tags: c#, wpf, arrangeoverride

I have the following

```
public class MatrixButton : Button
{
  public MatrixButton()
  {
    Height = 20;
    Width = 44;
    Content = "foo";
  }

  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    var measureOverride = new Size(44, 20);
    return measureOverride;
  }

  protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
  {
    var arrangeOverride = new Size(44, 20);
    return arrangeOverride;
  }
}
```

Now I put that button just in an empty window like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Content = new MatrixButton();

  }
}
```

For some reason that button is not visible in the window. Does anyone know why?
If I remove the overrides the button is displayed correct ofcourse...

**edit:**
the reason is that the button is integrated in a complex layout where there are a lot of them and the layout pass is consuming a lot of time but the button's size will be always the same

Comment: Where's the sense of all these overrides?. Just set Width and Height. Anyway, you may need to call the base class methods.

Comment: Like Clemens suggested I don't see the point but I recommend calling the base functions after you've done your work.  It is likely the base is handling some of the key values used to update the object properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you want to contrain the size, you still should call the base methods for the child elements of the `Button` to be measured and arranged as expected:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    var measureOverride = new Size(44, 20);
    base.MeasureOverride(measureOverride);
    return measureOverride;
}

protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
{
    var arrangeOverride = new Size(44, 20);
    base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeOverride);
    return arrangeOverride;
}
```

Comment: yea, i tried that with another control and it worked there. I guess the reason is that the button has children which needs to be arranged as well

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought I wrote in the answer.